# CSS Two Images Over Each Other

Tags: css

I have two images, one should go slightly above like this one.
[image]

This is what I have so far: http://www.ryansammut.com/orijen/products.html At the moment if I put it slightly downwards, the other image will get over the dogs image.

Comment: Do you use z-index attribute in your css?

Comment: now I do, it's re solved

Comment: dangit! this defeats the purpose of StackOverflow! This is for helping people in the future too, but since the website is down and no one copied the code here, this thread is virtually useless... I have the z-index set, and the elements are floating, but they still do not stack, and I was wondering what was done different in the HTML and the other CSS elements, but no research can be done now...

Comment: @BillyNair - did you try the !important attribute in your css?

Comment: No, I didnt, but I did find this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697674, and actually, that is EXACTLY what I was trying to do anyway. (I was going to do clipping and all of that, this way cut to the heart of what needed to be done)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can solve this giving your dogs image a higher [z-index](http://tjkdesign.com/articles/z-index/teach_yourself_how_elements_stack.asp) then the other one. (or just put it in the right order in the DOM)

In your case:

```
#dogsProducts {
 ...
 z-index: 2;
}
```

result:

[image: dog website zindex problem]

Comment: Thanks very much, didn't realize it was that simple.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the `#dogsProducts` rule and set its `z-index` to 1000 (*something big*).

```
#dogsProducts {
  height: auto;
  left: 430px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 830px;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```