# Continuously scroll a div background image by animating its X position

Tags: jquery, css, animation

There is an example of what I am trying to achieve here:

http://www.queness.com/resources/html/bgscroll/index.html

However it doesn't appear to work with recent versions of jQuery.

Comment: I just tested the example you linked to with the latest jquery and it works fine.

Answer (score 10):

http://jsfiddle.net/3tQsc/

Works perfectly fine