# How to slide a image in background in css?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to slide a background image like [this](http://www.infusionsoft.com/).  I want to implement this effect [here](http://dev.kcseocompany.com/clbusinesscoachings/buy-infusionsoft-now/).

I have used these css properties

```
-webkit-animation: sliding 60s linear infinite;
background-attachment:scroll;
```

But not working for me.

Please provide me right direction.

Comment: Where is your `sliding` definition?

Comment: you are tanlking about the part where : " Find out how Infusionsoft can help your small business succeed
Fill out the form to get started. " is written ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **[keyframe animations](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/)** for this.

```
@keyframes moveClouds {
    to {
        background-position: 100% 0;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes moveClouds {
    to {
        background-position: 100% 0;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes moveClouds {
    to {
        background-position: 100% 0;
    }
}
#clouds {
    height:300px;
    width:600px;
    background: #FFF url(http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/Kin/eyg/Kineyg4RT.svg) repeat-x 0 0;
    animation: moveClouds 20s linear infinite;
    -ms-animation: moveClouds 20s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: moveClouds 20s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: moveClouds 20s linear infinite;
}
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/umayr/EU6V8/)

Answer (score 1):

I think you have forgotten to add this to your css:

```
@-moz-keyframes sliding{
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: -1361px 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **@keyframes rule**.

Example -

```
@keyframes sliding {
    from {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
    to {
        background-position: 100% 0;
    }
}

.somediv {
    animation: sliding 60s linear infinite;
}
```

Don't forget to add vendor prefixes. Learn more about keyframe rules from [**here**](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp)

Answer (score 0):

[Continuously scroll a div background image by animating its X position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697674/continuously-scroll-a-div-background-image-by-animating-its-x-position)

Have a look at the answer in the above link. Hope it helps.