# Jquery css3 auto scroll image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I have this piece of code that I would modify

```
<section id="imgTestata1"  style="background-color:#f7f7f7; color:#ffffff;  background-image:url(../asset/images/scatti/home1.jpg); padding-top:290px; padding-bottom:0px; background-position:Right top; background-size:cover;">
<div class="row-inner row-inner-full">
    <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-12">
        <div class="vc_column-inner ">
            <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                <div class="colored-box wpb_animate_when_almost_visible wpb_bottom-to-top" style="max-width:550px; padding:35px 45px 50px; margin-left:40px;">
                    <img src="../asset/images/logo_trasparente.png" style="width:100%" />
                  </div>
                <div class="vc_spacer" style="height:40px"></div>
                <div class="sticky_navigation_wrapper">
                    <div class="sticky_navigation">
                        <div class="sn_inner">
                            <a href="#wrapper">
                                <div class="to_top"><i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></div>
                            </a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#innovazione">Innovazione</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#inside">What's inside</a></li>

                                <li><a href="#team">Our Team</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#features">Features</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to add a javascript function that can allow me change the background image in the section named "imgTestata1"
Thanks

Comment: what have you tried? and what does your question have to do with scrolling the image?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you want to change the image or scroll it (probably the first)? Anyway:

1. [Continuously scroll a div background image by animating its X position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697674/continuously-scroll-a-div-background-image-by-animating-its-x-position) To scroll
2. http://www.jqueryscript.net/slideshow/jQuery-Plugin-For-Auto-Background-Image-Switcher-easybg-js.html To autochange it, demo here
   http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Auto-Background-Image-Switcher-easybg-js/

Comment: I tried the second point but It doesn't work. I can't use the $ simbol in my template and I have to substitute it with the 'JQuery' word. The result is that the plugin doesn't work. I obtain the message easy bg is not a function.

Comment: There's plenty of options around, maybe one will fit what you need, examples: http://rewish.github.io/jquery-bgswitcher/, http://www.simonbattersby.com/blog/cycling-a-background-image-with-jquery/ and even pure css with webkit animations http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/01/02/fullscreen-background-image-slideshow-with-css3/.